# "that" vs "which" usage and change of meaning in context

Tags: relative-pronouns

Sentences in question:

> Our house, which has four bedrooms, is located in Ocean City.
>
> Our house that has four bedrooms is located in Ocean City.

I don't understand or see the difference between the two sentences.

May I receive an explanation?

Comment: Option three: *Our house which has four bedrooms is located in Ocean City.*  Not acceptable: *\*Our house, that has four bedrooms, is located in Ocean City.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> Our house, which has four bedrooms, is located in Ocean City.

*which has four bedrooms* is just describing the type of house. I think commas are optional.

In

> Our house that has four bedrooms is located in Ocean City.

seems to be a usage to differentiate it from your other houses. For example:

> Our house that has four bedrooms is located in Ocean City, and our house that has six bedrooms is located in River City.

Comment: But the commas (or in speech, intonation) determine whether it's a restrictive or non-restrictive relative.  So while "commas are optional" is true, it may be misleading without some elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

As another user already said.. `which` is being used here to elaborate on the subject (the house).

However, as others have pointed out, the commas are key to understanding the context.  If you put a comma and then the cluase

```
[...], that has four bathrooms [,]
```

You have a sentence that is identical in meaning to the one that is using `which`..

-- The sentence above is a perfect example, in itself, of how the absence of commas simply takes the **that** and uses it to describe and elaborate.

```
Our house, that we bought with blood money, just foreclosed.

Our house, which we bought with blood money, just foreclosed.
```

The two sentences are identical in meaning.

```
Our house that we bought with blood money just foreclosed.
```

This suggest there may be more than one house.... perhaps one with 6 bathrooms, or no bathrooms, and so on.

Then, you have sentences using `that which` in a compound form.
`Which` is still elaborating on a subject, but the subject is `that`

```
My dog eats that which he craves.
```

But sentences like that sound very Shakespearean.