# That Vs which; which one should I chose and why?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct (and why)..or are both options ok?

Look! That's the car *which* was reported as being stolen.

Or

Look! That's the car *that* was reported as being stolen!

Thanks

Comment: see: [1] [that vs which usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33407/that-vs-which-usage-and-change-of-meaning-in-context), and [2] [difference between _which_ and _that_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5/is-there-any-difference-between-which-and-that)

Answer (score 1):

"That" is used with restrictive clauses that limit the meaning or the sentence, or specify which noun among many is the subject.  "Which" is used with non-restrictive clauses that simply add additional, unnecessary information.  In this case, I believe "that" is the proper choice.

Here's a good reference:  https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/that_vs_which.html

Comment: Don't worry about a question being too old to answer or giving a late answer. Good answers are never too late, because people get constantly directed to this site when they google English grammar, even years after a question was first posted.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, They are both correct.
But for sounding smoothly (avoiding duplication), I think using "which" is better.